# PHP-socket_connect(): unable to connect [10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, sockets, client-server

I am running a client-server code in php for chatting. I am getting this error:
**socket_connect(): unable to connect [10061]: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

I have gone through many questions and answers on this problem but still unable to solve this.
Here is my code :

for user-1:

> 

```
$host   = "127.0.0.1";
$port_1 = 5001;
$port_2  = 50002;
// create socket
$socket_2 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$socket_1 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket_2, $host, $port_2) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  


socket_bind($socket_1, $host, $port_1) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
socket_listen($socket_1, 10) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
$new_socket= socket_accept($socket_1) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");


        $result = socket_read ($socket_1, 1024);

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $message = $_POST['client_message'];
        socket_write($socket_2, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
    }
    // or die("Could not read server response\n");
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
    }
    socket_close($socket_1);
    socket_close($socket_2);
    socket_close($new_socket);
?
```

> 

This is for user-2

```
$host   = "127.0.0.1";
$port_1 = 5001;
$port_2  = 50002;
// create socket
$socket_2 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$socket_1 = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket_2, $host, $port_2) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  


socket_bind($socket_1, $host, $port_1) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
socket_listen($socket_1, 10) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
$new_socket= socket_accept($socket_1) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");


        $result = socket_read ($socket_1, 1024);

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $message = $_POST['client_message'];
        socket_write($socket_2, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
    }
    // or die("Could not read server response\n");
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
    }
    socket_close($socket_1);
    socket_close($socket_2);
    socket_close($new_socket);
?>
```

please help me figuring out the errors.
Thank you

Comment: Are both of these running on the same machine? They both seem to be attempting to open sockets on the same ports, which isn't going to work if they are running on the same machine.

Comment: yeah they are running on the same machine,actually I want to make user-1 listening to one port and user-2 another.

Comment: To connect to a socket, the receiving socket should have already been listening. Usually using a loop waitin for incoming connection.

Comment: what should be the change in the above  code if I  want to run it correctly

Comment: For a start, make it so one of your scripts acts as a server (starts up first and waits for a connection on a fixed port) and the other is a client (starts up second and connects to the known fixed port using a randomly generated port).

Comment: @chris could you please make the changes in above code,because I have tried a lot to run this code

Comment: It's not as easy as making changes to the code @sharq. You will need to understand how socket works. The listening part should be something like [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-accept.php#82618). Run the listener using `exec nohup` from the terminal so it starts listening on that socket. But if you really want to build a chat application, I'm suggesting to take a look at XMPP.